# Efficient way of switching between different implementations of a logging function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

My Haskell webapp starts with a particular logging configuration. Once the webserver starts, the logging configuration cannot be changed. Here's what the logging config controls:

- logging output format: text logs (mostly used for local dev) vs JSON logs (mostly used for production env)
- whether to compute and emit aggregate metrics for each req/res, like number of SQL statements, number of downstream HTTP requests made, time spent in SQL, time spent in API calls, etc.
- log verbosity: in development env the actual SQL statements executed, detailed req/res logs of API calls made to downstream systems, etc. are logged. In production environment, these are skipped.

The naive way of writing a logging function would check, *for every log statement*, the logging config to determine (a) whether to output the log at all, (b) which format to use - text vs json, and (c) whether to update the aggregate metrics

Somehow this seems very inefficient to me.

Is it possible to *efficiently* do the following:

- upon application startup, depending upon the logging config, choose one of several implementations
- somehow inject this implementation into the application's monad (which might be an instance of `MonadLogger`), such that the compiler is still able to do any optimizations that it would have done otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Compare the following two functions:

```
convertData :: Loggable a => Bool -> a -> ByteString
convertData b x = case b of
    False -> viaString x
    True -> viaJSON x

convertCode :: Loggable a => Bool -> a -> ByteString
convertCode b = case b of
    False -> \x -> viaString x
    True -> \x -> viaJSON x
```

In GHC, if you write `convertData False`, then it will check and re-check this `Bool` on each call; while if you write `convertCode False`, the `Bool` is checked once (and a function that has already "internalized" that `Bool` is returned).

This generalizes to your other requirements as well. Simply write your logging function as a function which takes a logging config, does all its `case` statements and other checks immediately, then in each resulting case returns a specialized logging function that accepts the remaining arguments.

(Why the names `convertData` and `convertCode`? Because they are two versions of a `convert` function; one stores its config explicitly as closed-over data, while the other stores its config implicitly in the program counter.)

Comment: Interesting. Does `convertCode` need to explicitly evaluate to a lambda? Can this not be achieved by saying `covertCode = convertData True`? Wouldn't the in-build currying of Haskell deal with this automagically?

Comment: Next question would be how to "inject" this function into my app's monad? One option is to make this logging function a part of my `Env` data-structure, where `AppM = ReaderT Env IO`. The other option is to use type-classes. Can type-classes even be used in this case? And is there a perf difference between these two approaches?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda No, `convertData' = convertData True` is not as good. As mentioned in the answer: this creates a closure that stores the `True` explicitly, then checks the stored value on each subsequent call, as opposed to returning two different code pointers, each with no check inside, for the `True` and `False` cases. As for placing this in your environment or a class... well, I'm not super sure what it would mean for this to be in a class, so that's hard for me to answer.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I thought of another way to explain this that may be clearer for some people. Consider `convertDataTrue = convertData True` and `convertCodeTrue = convertCode True`. We can inline the two definitions and see the difference: `convertDataTrue = (\b x -> case b of { False -> f; True -> t }) True = \x -> case True of { False -> f; True -> t }` and here evaluation stops because it is a lambda and hence WHNF; `convertCodeTrue = (\b -> case b of { False -> f; True -> t }) True = case True of { False -> f; True -> t } = t`. In the latter, the `case` has been done once and for all.

Comment: What happens if `viaString` and `viaJSON` need some other configuration that is passed into `convertData`/`convertCode`? what would something like this do: `convertCode :: Loggable a => Bool -> Config -> a -> ByteString ; convertCode b cfg  = case b of { True -> \a -> viaJSON cfg a ; False ->  \a -> viaString cfg a }`

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Just calculate and see. `convertSaurabh True = (\b cfg -> case b of { ... }) True = \cfg -> case True of { ... }`. So the `case` will be evaluated every time you pass a config. Move the config argument into the case to fix. `convertSaurabh2 b = case b of { True -> \cfg a -> viaJSON cfg a; False -> \cfg a -> viaString cfg a }`.

Answer (score 3):

The basic approach you propose, where you do all the checks in the logging action has essentially this form:

```
log :: IO ()
log = do
   b <- isLogEnabled
   if b
   then actuallyLog
   else return ()  -- do nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let config = Config { logAction = log , ... }
   runServer config
```

You can, and should, move the check `isLogEnabled` in the main action:

```
actuallyLog :: IO ()
actuallyLog = do ...

doNothing :: IO ()
doNothing = return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
   b <- isLogEnabled  -- once and for all
   let log :: IO ()
       log = if b then actuallyLog else doNothing
   let config = Config { logAction = log , ... }
   runServer config
```

The `if` inside `log` will also be evaluated only once, effectively defining `log = actuallyLog` or `log = doNothing` with no overhead (after the first use).